# SAPUI5: Custom Control not loaded into Table groupHeaderFactory

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to create a Custom Group Header to be used in a sap.m.Table. In the groupHeaderFactory of my table the custom control should be loaded. The groupHeaderFactory method is defined in my formatter.js. I created a folder controls with a file CustomGroupHeader.js. At the moment it should just return the sap.m.GroupHeaderListItem. Later I want to add some custom functionality to my Custom Group Header.
However I cannot manage to load my Custom Control into my GroupHeaderFactory in my formatter.js.

CustomGroupHeader.js:

```
sap.sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/GroupHeaderListItem"
], function (GroupHeaderListItem) {
    "use strict";
    return GroupHeaderListItem.extend("ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor.ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor.controls.CustomGroupHeader", {
        metadata: {
            properties: {
            }
        },
        renderer: function (oRm, oControl) {
            GroupHeaderListItem.render(oRm, oControl);
        }
    });
});
```

formatter.js:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/GroupHeaderListItem",
    "ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor.ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor.controls.CustomGroupHeader"
], function (GroupHeaderListItem, CustomGroupHeader) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        createGroupHeader: function (oGroup) {

            return new CustomGroupHeader();
        }

    };

});
```

Worklist XML View:

```
<Table id="table" width="auto"
                                    items="{ path: '/PID_TrackingSet', filters : [{path: 'Lgnum', operator : 'EQ', value1 : 'NL1'}] , sorter: [{ path: 'Benum', group : true}], groupHeaderFactory: '.formatter.createGroupHeader'}"
                                    noDataText="{worklistView>/tableNoDataText}" busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" growing="false" growingScrollToLoad="true"
                                    updateFinished="onUpdateFinished" selectionChange="onPress" mode="SingleSelectMaster">
                                    <headerToolbar>
                                        <Toolbar>
                                            <Title id="tableHeader" text="{worklistView>/worklistTableTitle}"/>
                                            <ToolbarSpacer/>
                                            <SearchField id="searchField" tooltip="{i18n>worklistSearchTooltip}" search="onSearch" width="auto" liveChange="onLiveChange"></SearchField>
                                        </Toolbar>
                                    </headerToolbar>
                                    <columns>
                                        <Column id="ColBeNum">
                                            <Text text="{i18n>tableNColumnTitleBenum}" id="tableNColumnTitleBeTyp"/>
                                        </Column>
                                        <Column id="ColPid">
                                            <Text text="{i18n>tableNColumnTitlePid}" id="tableNColumnTitlePid"/>
                                        </Column>
                                        <Column id="ColBinid">
                                            <Text text="{i18n>tableNColumnTitleBinid}" id="tableNColumnTitleBinid"/>
                                        </Column>
                                        <Column id="ColState">
                                            <Text text="{i18n>tableNColumnTitleState}" id="tableNColumnTitleState"/>
                                        </Column>
                                    </columns>
                                    <items>
                                        <ColumnListItem type="Active" press="onPress">
                                            <cells>
                                                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Benum}" titleActive="true" titlePress="onItemTitleClick"/>
                                                <Text text="{Pid}"/>
                                                <Text text="{Binid}"/>
                                                <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'State' , formatter: '.formatter.formatState'}"/>
                                            </cells>
                                        </ColumnListItem>
                                    </items>
                                </Table>
```

Project Structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKhCL.png)

ErrorMessage:
Caused by: Error: failed to load 'ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor.ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor.controls.CustomGroupHeader.js' from resources/ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor.ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor.controls.CustomGroupHeader.js: 404 - error

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change dots to slashes in your dependency in formatter definition:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/GroupHeaderListItem",
    "ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor/ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor/controls/CustomGroupHeader"
], function (GroupHeaderListItem, CustomGroupHeader) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        createGroupHeader: function (oGroup) {

            return new CustomGroupHeader();
        }

    };

});
```

Comment: I see thank you for your answer. 
Unfortunately it did not completely resolve the issue. Now the error message is:

Caused by: Error: failed to load 'ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor/ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor/controls/CustomGroupHeader.js' from ./controls/CustomGroupHeader.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Comment: I see that in your code snippet you have **sap.sap.ui.define**. Change it to **sap.ui.define**

Comment: Thank again. 
Problem still persists:

Error: found in negative cache: 'ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor/ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor/controls/CustomGroupHeader.js' from ./controls/CustomGroupHeader.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Comment: Did you try empty cache and hard reload (available in Chrome)?

Comment: Did it now. New Error coming up:

Uncaught Error: "[object Object]" is not valid for aggregation "items" of Element sap.m.Table#ZPD_Consolidation_Monitor---worklist--table

Comment: OK, this is definitely another question. Seems that at least your module now is loaded.